# Calculating the averages iteratively and efficiently

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a long list of integers:

```
my_list = [10,13,42,23,12,45,33,59,12]
```

I want to calculate the averages of first `i` numbers, for all `i` in `0<i<n`.

I can basically do:

```
averages = [ sum(my_list[0:i]) * (1.0/i) for i in range(1,len(my_list)) ]
```

which gives me the correct results, but I think there should be a faster way of doing this since I can use the previous sums in the following calculations.

I guess there should be a faster solution with `numpy`, maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `numpy.cumsum`

```
In [13]: import numpy as np

In [14]: my_list = [10,13,42,23,12,45,33,59,12]

In [15]: np.cumsum(my_list) / np.arange(1, len(my_list)+1, dtype=np.float)
Out[15]: 
array([ 10.        ,  11.5       ,  21.66666667,  22.        ,
        20.        ,  24.16666667,  25.42857143,  29.625     ,  27.66666667])
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Python 3.2 or higher, see [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) (and `itertools.islice` if you're trying to get a running average for a subset of the inputs). For example, in your case (getting the running average for `n - 1` values in the input):

```
import itertools
my_list = [10,13,42,23,12,45,33,59,12]
sums = itertools.islice(itertools.accumulate(my_list), len(my_list) - 1)
# If you didn't intend to omit the final value, it's just:
# sums = itertools.accumulate(my_list)
averages = [accum / i for i, accum in enumerate(sums, start=1)]
```

Comment: Note: In your particular case, where the list is already in memory, you could just slice `my_list` directly instead of using `islice`, e.g. 
`sums = itertools.accumulate(my_list[:-1])`, but you'd want `islice` if the input was coming from a generator of some sort where direct slicing won't work.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to slice at all, I get the impression that the OP wants the whole list (and just made an error in the question) but will wait for the OP to confirm.

Comment: Possible. The example explicitly omits the last value, and for all 0<i<n would imply that omission is intentional. Hard to tell.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create a generator function that would also allow lazy evaluation or generation of the list in one go by casting the result into a `list`, and use the `enumerate` generator to generate the count of the current element over time.

```
>>> def average_series(items):
...     sum = 0
...     for i, item in enumerate(items, 1):
...         sum += item
...         yield float(sum) / i
... 
>>> list(average_series([10,13,42,23,12,45,33,59,12]))
[10.0, 11.5, 21.666666666666668, ..., 27.666666666666668]
```

You don't always have to rely on numpy for simple things like this.